# Generalized Hermite Function as eigenfunction of a differential operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, orthonormal, eigenfunctions, python

I'm going through this [paper](http://inmabb.criba.edu.ar/revuma/pdf/v54n1/v54n1a08.pdf).

The article defines function function $\phi_n^\mu(x)$ that is orthonormal on $L^2$ with measure $dm = dx$:
\begin{equation}
 \phi^\mu_n =\left(\frac{\gamma_\mu(n)}{\Gamma(\mu+\frac{1}{2})}\right)^\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}n!}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}H^\mu_n(x)x^\mu;  \mu,n\in{N},
\end{equation}

Also, it defines differential operator (one-dimensional case, $d=1$, $\mu_1=\mu$)

\begin{equation} \label{eq:hcal}
 \mathcal{H_\mu} = \frac{1}{2}\left( 
   \sum^d_{k=1}\left[
    \mathcal{D}^2_{\mu_k}-\frac{2\mu_k}{x} \left(
     \frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\mu_k-1
    \right)
   \right] -|x|^2 
 \right),
\end{equation}
where \begin{equation} \label{eq:dunkl}
 \mathcal{D}_\mu\phi(x)=\phi'(x) + \frac{\mu}{x}\left(
  \phi(x)-\phi(-x)
 \right),
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:dunkl2}
 (\mathcal{D}^2_\mu\phi)(x)=\phi''(x) + \frac{2\mu}{x}\phi'(x) - \frac{\mu}{x^2}\left(
  \phi(x)-\phi(-x)
 \right),
\end{equation}

It is said (in the paper) that $\phi$ is the eigenfunction of $\mathcal{H}^\mu$ operator, i.e. $-2(\mathcal{H}^\mu \phi_n^\mu) (x) = 2(n+\mu+1/2)\phi_n^\mu(x)$ for one-dimensional case.

I have the functions written in Python: dunkl2 for $\mathcal{D}_\mu$, and calh for $\mathcal{H}_\mu$ operator:

```
def genhermite(n,m,x): 
if(n==0):
    return 1
if(n%2==0):
    return (-1)**(n//2) * 2**n * misc.factorial(n//2) * special.eval_genlaguerre(n//2,m-1/2,x**2) / genfactorial(n,m)* misc.factorial(n)
else:
    return (-1)**(n//2) * 2**n * misc.factorial(n//2) * x * special.eval_genlaguerre(n//2,m+1/2,x**2) / genfactorial(n,m) * misc.factorial(n)

def genphi(n,m,x):
return np.sqrt(genfactorial(n,m)/special.gamma(m+1/2)) / (2**(n/2)*misc.factorial(n)) * np.exp(-x**2/2) * genhermite(n,m,x) * x**m

def dunkl2(n,m,func,x): 
return misc.derivative(func,x,0.001,2) + 2*m*(misc.derivative(func,x,0.001))/x - m*(func(x)-func(-x))/x**2

def calh(n,m,func,x):
return -dunkl2(n,m,lambda x: func(n,m,x),x) + 2*m/x*misc.derivative(lambda x: func(n,m,x),x,0.001) + (2*m/x*(m-1)+x**2)*func(n,m,x)

for i in range(0,10):
print("n =", i, "; m =", 10-i, "; x =", 1, "; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) =", calh(i,10-i,genphi,1)/genphi(i,10-i,1)
```

I test my Python functions by simply dividing both sides of the differential equation by $\phi_n^\mu(x)$ and checking if the result is $2(n+\mu+1/2)$, and this gives me the set of numbers below. But, as you can see, there's something wrong, at least because the resulting coefficient depends not only on $n$ and $\mu$, but on $x$ also.

Where is my mistake? I can assure you that this phi I use is indeed orthonormal.

Data:

```
n = 0 ; m = 9 ; x = 1 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 108.999910168
n = 1 ; m = 8 ; x = 1 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 74.9999101676
n = 2 ; m = 7 ; x = 1 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 75.0000086295
n = 3 ; m = 6 ; x = 1 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 49.0000086295
n = 4 ; m = 5 ; x = 1 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 49.0000089668
n = 5 ; m = 4 ; x = 1 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 31.0000089668
n = 6 ; m = 3 ; x = 1 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 30.9999828753
n = 7 ; m = 2 ; x = 1 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 20.9999828754
n = 8 ; m = 1 ; x = 1 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 20.9999722442
n = 9 ; m = 0 ; x = 1 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 18.9999722445

n = 0 ; m = 9 ; x = 2 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 77.5000026668
n = 1 ; m = 8 ; x = 2 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 61.0000026667
n = 2 ; m = 7 ; x = 2 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 53.9999972207
n = 3 ; m = 6 ; x = 2 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 41.4999972198
n = 4 ; m = 5 ; x = 2 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 36.5000043004
n = 5 ; m = 4 ; x = 2 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 28.0000043004
n = 6 ; m = 3 ; x = 2 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 24.9999862338
n = 7 ; m = 2 ; x = 2 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 20.4999862334
n = 8 ; m = 1 ; x = 2 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 19.4999826454
n = 9 ; m = 0 ; x = 2 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 18.9999826456
```

Comment: what is $L^2$ with measure $dx$ ? can you write $\|f\|^2$ or $\langle f,g \rangle$ explicitely ? apparently he is considering $dm = e^{-\sum_{k=1}^d|x_k|^2} \prod_{k=1}^d x_k^{2 \mu_k}  dx$ and $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f g \ dm$ i.e. the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d, m)$

Comment: and what is $\phi'(x)$  ?? are you considering $d=1$ ??

Comment: $\phi'(x)$ is 1st order derivative of $\phi(x)$, $d=1$(edited)

Comment: mu calculations say that $\int_R\phi^\mu_n\phi^\mu_mdx=\delta_{nm}$, i.e. $\phi$ is orthonormal with respect to $dm=dx$
correct me if i'm wrong please

Answer (score 1):

I'm no Python expert, but I believe your implementation of the operator $\mathcal{D}_\mu$ is
\begin{equation}
 \mathcal{D}_\mu \phi(x) = \phi''(x) +2 \frac{\mu}{x} \phi'(x) - \frac{\mu}{x^2} (\phi(x) - \phi(-x)),
\end{equation}
which is not the same as the operator description for $\mathcal{D}_\mu$ in your question.

**Edit based on updated question:** Another issue might be that there are two types of (generalised) Hermite polynomials, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Definition). From the article you cited (and the references therein), it's clear that they use the 'physicists' ' definition; the function $f(x)$ you test might use the 'probabilists' ' definition.

**Addition:** I used the definition from the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9307224v1.pdf), where $\Phi$ therein is the [Kummer confluent hypergeometric function $_1F_1$](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1/), to test in Mathematica whether $\phi_n^\mu$ is an eigenfunction of $\mathcal{H}_\mu$, and it turns out it's *not*. So, there might be something wrong with the operator expression for $\mathcal{H}_\mu$, which would mean that [this paper](http://inmabb.criba.edu.ar/revuma/pdf/v54n1/v54n1a08.pdf) contains a typo in equation (1.8).

More precisely, I obtain
\begin{equation}
-2 \mathcal{H}_\mu \phi_{2m}^\mu = 2\left(2m+2\mu+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\mu(\mu-1)}{x}\right)\phi_{2m}^\mu -2 (1+2m+2\mu)\frac{\mu}{(1+2m)x} \phi_{2m+1}^\mu
\end{equation}

Comment: my bad, didin't include the definition of $\mathcal{D}^2_\mu$ in the question(edited)

Comment: Ok, no problem. There might be other issues; I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Btw, the original derivation of the eigenfunctions is found here: [https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9307224v1.pdf], in the proof of Thm 3.6.

Comment: thanks for the answer. would you tell me how did you obtain this formula? i'll also check it.
maybe there's some recursion relation for $\phi^\mu_n$ which is close to, but not exactly (1.8), in case there IS a typo? i'll try to find something.


and may i use your formula, if it's right, in my work? i'll just put a reference to your answer or something

Comment: i've also updated my question with my Python definitions of $\phi_n^\mu$ and Generalized Hermite Polynomial

Comment: Sure, feel absolutely free to use the formula, but be sure to check it! I obtained it using Mathematica, where I used the functional description of $\phi_n^\mu$ in terms of $_1F_1$, and applied the operator $\mathcal{H}_\mu$ to it. I checked here [ http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1/17/01/01/ ] if there are any recursive relations for $_1F_1$ which allows you to express $\phi_{2m+1}^\mu$ in terms of $\phi_{2m}^\mu$, but as the defining differential equation for $_1F_1$ is second order, the recurrence relation involves *both* neighbours, not just one.